# Navigation controller popViewControllerAnimated : yes is not working as expected

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

I am using following line of code:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But it is not behaving in ios 7 as it doing in ios 6.Some times it does not pop controller while we are pressing back button 2- 3 times in succession.
Resulting in abrupt behaviour in navigation bar and deallocating a controller but showing the same on ui .
So when we press anything on that controller it results to a crash since controller is already deallocated.

Comment: I'm happy that I am not the only one this has happened to. iOS 7+ bug (just got it in iOS 8, too). The view is popped from the navigation stack, but not animated from the UI. Then it gets stuck there, since it's no longer a part of the stack!

Answer (score 10):

Check if you're running the code on the UI thread

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [(UINavigationController *)tabBarController.selectedViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        });
worked for me with a similar problem

Answer (score 7):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This method will navigate to the root of your navigationController.

You can check your viewController hierachy With following code.

```
    NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);
```

Comment: ues NSLog to check your navigationController hierachy.

Comment: use popToRootViewControllerAnimated method

Comment: @SidShah, popToRootViewController will get back to the root of navigationStack, but what if you want to come back in succession 2-1-0

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this problem with this way:

```
 dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                     UINavigationController * nav = tabbarControl.selectedViewController;
                                                                     [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[nav setViewControllers:@[[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]] animated:NO];
                                                                tabbarControl.selectedIndex = 0;
 });
```

When you delay one second the view will pop from UI, then the view will pop from the navigation stack, I think is the problem of the animation serial.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on iOS 8.

I solved by subclassing UINavigationController and adding this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.delegate = self;
}

- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
}
```

I basically block all the user interactions during the pop animation. I know it's a dirty solution, but it's the only one that I found that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that should be working without dispatch_async.
I got to the same issue, but i got to know the reason.

We should check it if the current scene is assigned to a proper view controller name in the storyboard.(identity inspector -> class)

If you connect a button action to m file and then insert the name of the view controller, that is not working.

So, you should delete the connect, and you insert the proper view controller name, and then you should connect the action to m file again.

Answer (score 0):

I created my project from master-detail template, that uses split view controller. In my case, removing the split view controller resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is important that that calls to `popViewController(animated:)`, `popToRootViewController(animated:)` and related calls be made in the main queue, but under some conditions this doesn't seem to be good enough, and the animation doesn't occur.

I was able to fix it as described in some other answers here, performing the pop navigation *later* in the main queue. The Swift equivalent:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.rootViewController.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

This might be explained by other animations that are still in progress, and by scheduling the block this way it happens at the end of the current work taking place or currently scheduled in the main queue, which allows the animation to execute correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code for popup a view controller from navigation stack

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count -2] animated:YES];
```

Comment: can you please explain your answer?